# If $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal then $|V_\kappa|=\kappa$

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to do one of the exercises from Jech chapter 6 as follows:

If $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal then  $|V_\kappa|=\kappa$

Now clearly we have that $\kappa \leq |V_\kappa|$ as $\kappa \subset V_\kappa$ by definition of $V_\kappa$

> Now to show that $|V_\kappa| \leq \kappa$

I am confused as how to show this, we can show that for every $\alpha < \kappa$ we have $\kappa> \aleph_\alpha$

So now I want to do something with $|V_\kappa|=|\cup_{\alpha<\kappa} V_\alpha|$ but I am not sure what?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want more than $\kappa>\aleph_\alpha$. The size of $V_{\omega+\alpha}$ is $\beth_\alpha$, the result of iterating $\alpha$ times the function $\lambda\mapsto 2^\lambda$, starting with $\aleph_0$. You need to show that $\kappa>\beth_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We proceed by transfinite induction to show that $\left|V_\alpha\right|<\kappa$ for every $\alpha < \kappa$. For successor ordinals we use (and need) the strong inaccessibility:
$$
\left|V_{\alpha+1}\right|=2^{\left|V_\alpha\right|}<\kappa
$$
since $\left|V_\alpha\right|<\kappa$. For limit ordinals,
$$
\left|V_\alpha\right|=\left| \bigcup_{\xi<\alpha}V_\xi \right|\leq \sum_{\xi<\alpha}\left|V_\xi\right|< \kappa
$$
since $\kappa$ is regular.